# How to delete an object from a map which contains a vector as value in C++

Tags: c++

I have a map which contains a of vector of type Messages.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Message>> storage;
```

class Message has 3 member variables.

```
class Message
{
private:
    std::string msg;
    std::string msg_type;
    int priority;
}
```

Now i am trying to delete an object which has priority(say 3) from the map. i am using the following function for it. But it doesn't work.

```
void deleteByMessagePriority(int priority)
{
    if (checkPriorityOfMessage(priority))
    {

        for (std::map<std::string, std::vector<Message>>::iterator it = storage.begin(); it != storage.end(); it++)
        {
            std::vector<Message> listOfMsgs = it->second;
            for (std::vector<Message>::iterator vec_it = listOfMsgs.begin(); vec_it != listOfMsgs.end(); vec_it++)

            //for(int index = 0;index < listOfMsgs.size();index++)
            {
                if (vec_it->getPriority() == priority)
                {
                    listOfMsgs.pop_back();
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *But it doesn't work.* How doesn't it work?

Comment: `listOfMsgs.pop_back();` won't delete  `vec_it`, it will delete last element of `listOfMsgs`. Look for `vector::erase` also do not forget, that erase invalidates all iterators

Comment: slightly tangential but I think worth saying: If you're iterating through a map to filter out items on a value criteria, shouldn't that value be in the map's key?

Answer (score 3):

Look carefully at this:

```
            if (vec_it->getPriority() == priority)
            {
                listOfMsgs.pop_back();
            }
```

You're looking at the priority of one message (the one referred to by `vec_it`), but then what are you deleting if it matches?

Instead of writing your own loop, I'd use `erase` and `std::remove_if` to remove all the items you care about in that vector at once.

```
for (auto & item : storage) {
    auto &vec = item.second;
    auto start_junk = std::remove_if(
        vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
        [=](Message const &m) { return m.priority == priority; });
    vec.erase(start_junk, vec.end());
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error - 
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Message, _Alloc=std::allocator<Message>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)              argument types are: (std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Message>>>, std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Message>>>)
            object type is: const std::vector<Message, std::allocator<Message>>

Comment: @sohan: I've corrected the code. I'd accidentally used a reference to const, which (of course) prevents us from modifying the data it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (vec_it->getPriority() == priority)
{
   listOfMsgs.pop_back();
```

`pop_back()` removes the last element of the vector which you don't want.You want to check [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)
Also remember `erase()` invalidates the iterators so you need iterator to the next element after a deleted element for which we can fortunately use return value of `erase`

```
if (vec_it->getPriority() == priority)
    {
       vec_it = listOfMsgs.erase(vec_it); //returns iterator to the element after vec_it which can also be `listOfMsgs.end()`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it delete only one element with the matching priority. If i have more than one message object it just deletes one. Now i have changed the code.

Comment: @sohan Why would it delete just one.You still have the loop.Right?

Comment: yes i have the loop.I have inserted the elements- Message a("hello1", "yellow", 1);
  interstMessages(a, checkMessageType, checkPriorityOfMessage);
  Message b("hello2", "yellow", 3);
  interstMessages(b, checkMessageType, checkPriorityOfMessage);
  Message c("hello3", "red", 3);
  interstMessages(c, checkMessageType, checkPriorityOfMessage);
  Message d("hello4", "red", 1);
  interstMessages(d, checkMessageType, checkPriorityOfMessage);
  Message e("hello5", "red", 1);
  interstMessages(e, checkMessageType, checkPriorityOfMessage);

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<Message> listOfMsgs = it->second;
.
.
.
listOfMsgs.pop_back();
```

You're copying the list, only to modify the copy. What you meant is:

```
std::vector<Message>& listOfMsgs = it->second;
```

Then you can proceed erasing elements. As Gaurav Sehgal says, use the return value of erase:

```
std::vector<Message>::iterator vec_it = listOfMsgs.begin();
while (vec_it != listOfMsgs.end())
{
    if (vec_it->getPriority() == priority)
    {
        vec_it = listOfMsgs.erase(vec_it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++vec_it;
    }
}
```